# how to find parent element that has specific child using By.xpath()?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Recently i've been scrapping by using selenium-webdriver in nodejs for a few days. 
so i have to find element has specific child element but i don't know how find it.

i have used following operator but it doesn't work

**By.xPath("tr[contains(@class, 'datetime2')]")**

following html

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="bacrgound-color:#eee">
      <td class="datetime2">
        20:00
      </td>
    <tr>
    
    <tr></tr>
    
    <tr style="bacrgound-color:#eee">
      <td class="datetime2">
        21:00
      </td>
    <tr>
    
    <tr style="bacrgound-color:#eee">
      <td class="datetime2">
        22:00
      </td>
    <tr>
    
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

i need to find only 'tr' that include element `<td class="datetime2">`. not `<tr></tr>`

how find this element By using By.xpath()??  please help me

Comment: There is no class `datetime2` in this html.

Comment: //td[@class='datetime2']/parent::tr

Comment: @Guy oops sorry now I just modified it.

Comment: @Grasshopper Wow really Thanks!!! it reall work well welllll really really thanks!! and //tr[td[@class='data']] too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try with following x-path.

```
//tr[td[@class='datetime2']]
```